# How to use spring cloud in development environment to create microservices

Tags: spring-boot

How to use spring cloud in development environment to create microservices I made a structure that appears the service in the Eureka dashboard but when I run my service in the browser it gives a Not Found error. I'll post my code here to see if anyone can help me.

ApiGatewayApplication.java:

```
package com.example.apigateway;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class ApiGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.application.name = eureka-server
server.port = 8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka = false
eureka.client.fetch-registry = false
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost

#spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.enabled=false
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id = user
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri = lb://USER-SERVICE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates = Path=/user/**
#spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters = RewritePath=/user/(?.*), /$\{path}
```

UserApplication.java:

```
package com.example.user;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class UserApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

UserController.java:

```
package com.example.user;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

//@Controller// This means that this class is a Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/user") // This means URL's start with /demo (after Application path)
@RestController
public class UserController {
  @Autowired // This means to get the bean called userRepository
         // Which is auto-generated by Spring, we will use it to handle the data
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @GetMapping("/")
  public String getHelloWorld()
  {
    return "Hello World";
  }


  @PostMapping(path="/add") // Map ONLY POST Requests
  public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestParam String name
      , @RequestParam String email) {
    // @ResponseBody means the returned String is the response, not a view name
    // @RequestParam means it is a parameter from the GET or POST request

    User n = new User();
    n.setNome(name);
    n.setEmail(email);
    userRepository.save(n);
    return "Saved";
  }

  @GetMapping(path="/all")
  public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
    // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
    return userRepository.findAll();
  }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:Mysql}:3306/quitanda_app
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
#spring.jpa.show-sql: true
server.port = 8000
spring.application.name = user-service
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
```

When I run **http://localhost:8761/** it returns me:

[image]

When I call my controller **http://localhost:8761/user/all**
it return to me:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Sep 26 20:16:15 BRT 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

Does anyone know how to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

folder **api-gateway** : EurekaServer:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class ApiGatewayApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

api-gateway: application.properties

```
spring.application.name = api-gateway
server.port = 8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka = false
eureka.client.fetch-registry = false
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

api-gateway: pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api-gateway</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

folder **routing**: routing our services:

```
package com.example.routing;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class RoutingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RoutingApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

routing: application.properties:

```
server.port=8080
spring.application.name=routing
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true

#spring.main.web-application-type=reactive
spring.cloud.gateway.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=user
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://USER
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates=Path=/user/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=testes
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://TESTES
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates=Path=/testes/**
```

routing: pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>routing</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>routing</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

folder **testes**: Class Application:

```
package com.example.testes;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class TestesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

testes: Controller:

```
package com.example.testes.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

//import com.example.user.communication.PaymentCartCommunication;

//@Controller// This means that this class is a Controller
@RequestMapping("/testes")// This means URL's start with /demo (after Application path)
@RestController
public class TestesController {

  @GetMapping("/message")
  public String getHelloWorld()
  {
    return "Hello World testes";
  }

}
```

testes: application.properties:

```
server.port = 8762
spring.application.name = testes
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
```

testes: pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>testes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>testes</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

folder **user**: Class application:

```
package com.example.user;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class UserApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserApplication.class, args);
    }


}
```

user: Controller:

```
package com.example.user.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


//@Controller// This means that this class is a Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")// This means URL's start with /demo (after Application path)
@RestController
public class UserController {

  @GetMapping("/message")
  public String getHelloWorld()
  {
    return "Hello World";
  }


}
```

user: application.properties:

```
server.port = 8000
spring.application.name = user
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
```

user: pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>user</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>user</name>
    <description>User microservice</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Run each project in a terminal and access the services : http://localhost:8080/testes/message http://localhost:8080/user/message

[Repository](https://github.com/rafaelsouzaribeiro/microservices-springboot-microservicos-springboot)